# RadGrid Row Selection when clicking Edit

Tags: vb.net, radgrid

I have a RadGrid that allows row selection(Checkbox). When I click on the edit button, I want that row to be selected.

I know this should be very simple, but just cant seem to find something that allows me to do this.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can anyone assist ?

Answer (score 0):

So I couldnt waste any more time on this, so I found another solution that ultimately worked out better.

I removed the AllowSelection from the RadGrid(i.e. The Checkbox was removed) and I retrieved thePrimary key(DataKey) from the RadGrid from within the EditCommand Event(Which is fired after clicking edit) and stored this in a hiddenfield :

```
Protected Sub rGVDELTaskLog_EditCommand(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs) Handles rGVDELTaskLog.EditCommand
    Dim rowindex As Integer

    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim dataItem As GridDataItem = CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)

        rowindex = dataItem.ItemIndex

        Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(rGVDELTaskLog.Items(rowindex), GridDataItem)

        HidDEL_Task_LogID.Value = item.GetDataKeyValue("pkiDEL_Task_Log")
    End If
End Sub
```

This way I got the ID from the row I was Editing.